# Excel VBA Can you set DataObject as text from File?

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to get the contents of a text file and add it to the clip board?

I am thinking along the lines of setting the contents of the DataObject as the contents from a file and then adding the DataObject to the clipboard.

Is this something you can do from Excel VBA?

This is the Code I am using to get the data into a txt file in the correct format. However, I also require it in the clipboard so I can just paste it.

```
With ws2
    Open "C:\Users\peter.carr\Documents\New Action Plan\copytest.txt" For Append As #1
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lastcol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For i = lastrow To 2 Step -1
        str1 = ""
        Print #1, ws2.Cells(i, 1).Value & ") " & ws2.Cells(i, 2).Value
        Print #1,
            For Each cell In .Range(.Cells(i, 6), .Cells(i, lastcol))
                g = i - 1
                If cell.Column <> 4 And cell.Column <> 5 And cell.Value <> "" And cell.Value <> "NEW ACTION" Then
                    Print #1, cell.Value
                    Print #1, "(" & cell.Offset(-g, 0).Value & ")"
                    Print #1,
                End If
            Next cell
        Next i
    Close #1
End With
```

I know I could just open the file and copy it. However, the idea is that this is part of a larger process to automate things, hence I really want to be able to fo this without opening the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub TextToClipboard()
    Dim sFile As String: sFile = "C:\Test.txt"
    Dim sText As String
    Dim Dataobj As DataObject
    Set Dataobj = New DataObject    
    Open sFile For Input As #1    
    sText = Input(LOF(1), 1)    
    Dataobj.SetText sText    
    Dataobj.PutInClipboard
End Sub
```

Comment: Am I correct in assuming I can just add Dataobj.PutInClipboard at the end to add it to the clipboard?

Comment: Yes, it should work as expected. I'm going to edit my answer.